# Create unique username for Swift/Firestore app

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, uniqueidentifier

I've done a lot of research through Firebase documentation, Swift/Xcode documentation, and here at Stack Overflow. Unfortunately, I have not been able to find a coherent and working solution to this problem--and it seems like this problem has been attempted many times in many different ways.

I'm not a professional coder. Needless to say, I'm figuring this out and teaching my children as we go along with this as a coding project to help them learn.

End goal: Allow swift/xcode application to create a user, but only if that user's userName is not already taken.

Relevant Stack Overflow discussions:

- [Cloud Firestore: Enforcing Unique User Names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47405774/cloud-firestore-enforcing-unique-user-names)
- [Firestore Security Rule to Check if Character Username Already Exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52016426/firestore-security-rule-to-check-if-character-username-already-exists/52017880#52017880)
- [Firestore Unique Index or Unique Constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47543251/firestore-unique-index-or-unique-constraint)

I will attach my current Swift code and I will update it as I make progress on this issue. The current code is for an Xcode view controller for a signup process. This code creates two different collections in the firestore database: "users"--which contains the user's profile information, and "usernames"--which is essentially an index of all usernames.

This index (collection: usernames) has a document named after each username. The idea is to create a firebase rule that will not allow a user to create an account in which username = (name of document in collection: usernames).

### Updates

It seems like there may be a couple of ways to accomplish the end goal. One is organically in the swift code, but that may have security issues as the code could potentially be bypassed by a nefarious actor. The other way is through rules in the firebase database, but I'm not as fluent in doing this (I'll do more research and report back). Perhaps the best course of action would be to do both.

This is the current code.

Version 1--the initial upload of code with the stated problem.

```
//  SignUpViewController.swift
//  Copyright © 2020 by Mix. All rights reserved.
//  Version 1.

import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseFirestore

class SignUpViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var signUpButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var errorLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var userNameTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var verifyPassTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var firstNameTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var lastNameTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var stateTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var birthdayTextField: UITextField!
    
    let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
    let id = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
    let email = Auth.auth().currentUser!.email
    
 let state_arr = ["", "AL", "AK", "AZ", "AR", "CA", "CO", "CT", "DE", "FL", "GA", "HI", "ID", "IL", "IN", "IA", "KS", "KY", "LA", "ME", "MD", "MA", "MI", "MN", "MS", "MO", "MT", "NE", "NV", "NH", "NJ", "NM", "NY", "NC", "ND", "OH", "OK", "OR", "PA", "RI", "SC", "SD", "TN", "TX", "UT", "VT", "VA", "WA", "WV", "WI", "WY"]
    
    //picker view
    let statePickerView = UIPickerView()
    //Hold Current arr
    var currentArr : [String] = []
    //that hold current text field
    var activeTextField : UITextField?
    
    func createDatePicker() {
        let toolbar = UIToolbar()
        toolbar.sizeToFit()
        
       let done2Button = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Select", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(doneTapped2))
           let space2Button = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
           
           toolbar.setItems([space2Button, done2Button], animated: false)

        birthdayTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
        birthdayTextField.inputView = datePicker
        
        datePicker.datePickerMode = .date
        
    }
    
    
    
    
   
    
    
    
override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
    
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    activeTextField = textField
    switch textField {
    case stateTextField:
    currentArr = state_arr
    default:
        
        print("Default")
    }
        return true
    }
    

    
  
    
    
    
    
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
            return 1
        }
        
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return currentArr.count
        }
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
            return currentArr[row]
        }
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
            print("Selected item is", currentArr[row])
            activeTextField!.text = currentArr[row]
        }
func createToolbar() {
       let toolbar = UIToolbar()
    toolbar.barStyle = .default
    toolbar.sizeToFit()
    
    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Select", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(doneTapped))
    let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(cancelTapped))
    toolbar.setItems([cancelButton,spaceButton, doneButton], animated: false)
    
    stateTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
    }
    
@objc func doneTapped() {
        activeTextField?.resignFirstResponder()
        }
   
@objc func cancelTapped() {
        
        activeTextField?.resignFirstResponder()
        }
   
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.errorLabel.alpha = 0
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false)
        setUpElements()
        createToolbar()
        createDatePicker()
    stateTextField.delegate = self
    statePickerView.delegate = self
    statePickerView.dataSource = self
    stateTextField.inputView = statePickerView
                     }
                     
func setUpElements() {
        Utilities.styleFilledButton(signUpButton)
                     }
func validateFields() -> String? {
        if firstNameTextField.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines) == "" ||
            lastNameTextField.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines) == "" ||
            emailTextField.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines) == "" ||
            passwordTextField.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines) == "" ||
            verifyPassTextField.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines) == "" ||
            userNameTextField.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines) == "" ||
            stateTextField.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines) == "" ||
            birthdayTextField.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines) == ""
    {
    return "Please fill in all fields."
     }
                let cleanedPassword = passwordTextField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
                
                if Utilities.isPasswordValid(cleanedPassword) == false {
                    // Password isn't secure enough
                    return "Please make sure your password is at least 8 characters, contains a special character and a number."
    }
    
                    if passwordTextField.text != verifyPassTextField.text {
                      // Password isn't secure enough
                      return "Passwords do not match."
                  }
    
    
    return nil
    
    }

    
    
    
    
@IBAction func termsButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
    
@IBAction func policyButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
    
@IBAction func signUpTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    verifyState()
    self.errorLabel.alpha = 0
 
   
    let error = validateFields()
            if error != nil {
                   showError(error!)
               }
            else {
                   
                   // Create cleaned versions of the data
                    let firstName = firstNameTextField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
                    let lastName = lastNameTextField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
                    let email = emailTextField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
                    let password = passwordTextField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
                    let username = userNameTextField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
                    let state = stateTextField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
                    let birthday = birthdayTextField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
                   
                   // Create the user
                Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (result, err) in
                    
                       // Check for errors
                       if err != nil {
                           
                           // There was an error creating the user
                           self.showError("Error creating user")
                       }
                       else {
                           
                           // User was created successfully, now store the first name and last name
                           let db = Firestore.firestore()
                           
                        db.collection("users").document(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).setData( ["firstname":firstName, "lastname":lastName, "username":username, "email": email, "birthday":birthday, "state":state, "uid": Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid]) { (error) in
                               
                               if error != nil {
                                   // Show error message
                                   self.showError("Error saving user data")
                               }
                           }
                        
                        
                        db.collection("usernames").document(username).setData( ["username":username, "email": email, "uid"
                            : Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid]) { (error) in
                                                     
                                                     if error != nil {
                                                         // Show error message
                                                         self.showError("Error saving user data")
                                                     }
                            
                    
                            
                                                 }
                        
                           
                           // Transition to the home screen
                           self.transitionToHome()
                       }
                       
                   }
      
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
    }
    
@IBAction func termsSwitch(_ sender: UISwitch) {
           
        self.view.endEditing(true)
              if (sender.isOn == true)
              {signUpButton.isEnabled = true}
        else if (sender.isOn == false)
              {signUpButton.isEnabled = false}
              }
    
    
func showError(_ message:String) {
              
              errorLabel.text = message
              errorLabel.alpha = 1
          }
          
func transitionToHome() {
              let HomeTabViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: Constants.Storyboard.homeTabViewController) as? HomeTabViewController
              
              view.window?.rootViewController = HomeTabViewController
              view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
              
          }
func verifyState() {
if stateTextField.text == "" {
    self.showError("Select a State.")
    return
    
}
}
   
    
func verifyPassword() {
    if passwordTextField.text == verifyPassTextField.text {
        
    }
    else {
        self.showError("Passwords do not match.")
        return
    }
    }
    
    @objc func doneTapped2() {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateStyle = .medium
        formatter.timeStyle = .none
        birthdayTextField.text = formatter.string(from: datePicker.date)
        self.view.endEditing(true)
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no out the box solution for this. You're already using `Auth.auth().createUser` which will make sure that the email is unique but there's no alternative with usernames.

I believe rules in the database will not work as Authentication and Database are two separate products that don't read each others data. Database rules are there to prevent access to data in the database but not to authentication service which is where you will need to be checking for the usernames.

I think the easiest option if you're just learning it to do the checking on the client. While it may not be 100% best option in terms of security for a first pass it might be the best. This could be accomplished by fetching user IDs from the server every time the user changes the username and only letting the user continue to `Auth.auth().createUser` code if the username does not yet exist.

A more involved option that would cover your security concern would be to use a Firebase Cloud Functions. These are small snippets of code (there is no swift option currently) that live on your firebase back-end and are run whenever an event or a call occurs. [More info on cloud functions.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions)

If you were to go that route there is a lot of guides online. I would go about it by creating a [function that can be called from the app directly](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) whenever the user tried to create a new account. I would pass the information the user is trying to sign up with as well and then have the checking for existing username and the actual account creation (`Auth.auth().createUser`) on the back-end function as well and pass back only the information that the your app requires (was it successful, did it fail, what is the username id...). This would solve the security concerns but would be a quite significant increase of effort to make it work.

Comment: Ben, thanks for the comment. Am I correct in saying that the .uid for authentication is just a randomly assigned alphanumeric? There is no way to customize this correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. User uid is generated when the user authentication creates the user.

Comment: Thanks...I've kind of just dived right into this. My kids are absolutely loving it, but I'm running out of tricks lol. My limited experience with coding "basic" in gradeschool is reallyt helping out though!