# Firestore duplicate verification conditions

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

My Firestore database looks like this

[image]

For documents I use dynamic IDs. I do not use the user ID in the path, it is stored in the field. The fields have the values `user` and `active`.

How can I prevent adding new entries if, for example,  the user 37870283 already has an active = true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to ensure the uniqueness of a field **value** in Firestore security rules. The only ways to ensure uniqueness are:

1. Use the thing that needs to be unique as the document ID.
2. Perform all writes from a single, trusted process (like Cloud Functions), and use transactions there.

Also see:

- [Cloud Firestore: Enforcing Unique User Names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47405774/cloud-firestore-enforcing-unique-user-names)
- [Prevent duplicate entries in Firestore rules not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54236388/prevent-duplicate-entries-in-firestore-rules-not-working/54238476#54238476)
- [Firestore security rule to check if character username already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52016426/firestore-security-rule-to-check-if-character-username-already-exists/52017880#52017880)

And more from [this list](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bgoogle-cloud-firestore%5d%5bfirebase-security%5d%20unique)